# "The end of next week" or "the end of the next week"?

Tags: grammaticality, definite-articles

I wonder if there should be a *the* in front of *week* in "the end of next week". Context:

> I will give you updates on how things work out by the end of next
>   week.

Comment: There's insufficient context to answer this question. Please provide a complete sentence, or maybe even three, that establish a context. Both phrases are grammatical and possible, but they'd be used in different contexts.

Comment: Both are correct, depending on what you mean to say. The question has no substance the way it stands now.

Comment: While I agree that this is a very basic question, I don't think it deserves to be closed. Both Kris and I have made the same two points: two different meanings & insufficient context. @Tim: Please edit the Q to give it a context.

Comment: @BillFranke: Edited... ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current week began on Monday 19 November. Any reference to the end of the week that begins on Monday 26 November would be to *the end of next week*. Any reference to any other week would normally be to *the end of the following week*. I’m not sure that *the end of the next week* is ever needed, but, as always, I should be interested to hear of counter-examples.

Answer (score 2):

Both "The end of next week" and "the end of the next week" are right, it's depending upon you what you mean to say.